# Torsion in the Real Projective Plane

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I'm trying to understand *precisely* why and how some closed curves are not boundaries while their "doubles" are.
I know that taking any curve connecting antipodal points on $S^2$ projects to a closed curve $\gamma$ in $\mathbb R \mathbb P^2$ that generates $\pi_1 (\mathbb R \mathbb P^2)$. The peculiar claim is that although $\gamma$ is not a boundary of any region of $\mathbb R \mathbb P^2$, $\gamma ^2$ is. I've read a bunch of questions and answers on MSE and watched a bunch of GIFs, and I can now visualise pretty well why $\gamma ^2$ is a boundary. (The belt trick worked pretty well for me.) I'm still pretty disoriented (hah) about why $\gamma$ is necessarily *not* a boundary. The closest I verbal explanation I have encountered is an excerpt from Gray's *Worlds out of Nothing*, which you see below. I'd much like a *surgical* explanation of both why $\gamma$ does not disconnect $\mathbb R \mathbb P^2$, and (less important but also much desired) exactly how $\gamma ^2$ does disconnect $\mathbb R \mathbb P^2$.

---

[image]

---

As was recommended in several MSE answers, I read page 170 in Stillwell's *Classical Topology and Combinatorial Group Theory*. I'll add more places I tried I need be.

I'd like to stress that I spent several hours reading drawing and thinking before posting this, and I'm aware of the relevant MSE questions, but I want to understand *exactly* what's going on here and so far I'm unable. Please do not reply tersely or vaguely :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think to $\mathbb{RP}^2$ as the Moebius strip with a disk glued along the boundary: if you draw  $\mathbb{RP}^2$ as the square with the edges identified and you take out a neghborhood of an edge (that is a disk) you can see it.

From this viewpoint it is clear the middle circle of the Moebius strip does not disconnet it (and thus it doesn't disconnect  $\mathbb{RP}^2$).

While the boundary of the Moebius strip is exactly the double of the middle circle and it divide  $\mathbb{RP}^2$ in a disk and in the Moebius strip.

Comment: Took me a few days but I understand now. A (probably minor) detail that's still bugging me - the boundary of the Mobius strip is not *exactly* twice the middle circle, it's homotopic to it. We want the same curve for $\gamma$ and $\gamma ^2$ no? How to resolve this?

Comment: Because they are homologous, and we only care about homology classes.

Comment: Yes, since their difference bounds the Moebius strip cut along its central circle. Another way to see what $\gamma^2$ bounds you can look at the usual representation of $\mathbb{RP}^2$ as in this picture (http://i.stack.imgur.com/ptPmY.png). In this case $\gamma$ is $a$:so $\gamma^2=a^2$ and it bounds the grey disk.